# How do I groupby dataset in mutiple columns on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my the dataset

```
OUTLET CODE  WEEK
000052         31
000052         27
000052         39
000035         29
000035         31
000035         38
000038         38
000038         29
000038         31
```

Here's what I try

```
df.groupby(['OUTLET_CODE', 'WEEK']).count()
```

Here's the output

```
OUTLET_CODE   WEEK
000035         29
               31
               38
000038         29
               31
               38
000052         27
               29
               31
               39
```

Here's type of output that I want

```
                                 WEEK
OUTLET_CODE            27 29 31 38 39
000035                  0  1  1  1  0
000038                  0  1  1  1  0
000052                  1  1  1  0  1
```

How suppose I do this?

Comment: Do you want `MultiIndex` in columns?

Comment: It is OK @jezrael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='WEEK', index='OUTLET_CODE', columns='WEEK', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
```